How do you return a value from a switch statement's matched case code block in zig?
Zig documentation says to leave the last line as an expression and that expression will be returned.
This documentation doesn't cover this case specifically but also didn't provide any clarity on the subject.
So this should work, as far as I can tell from the documentation.
const token = switch (c) {
        '.' => Token{ .type = .Dot, .value = null },
        '*' => Token{ .type = .Star, .value = null },
        '+' => Token{ .type = .Plus, .value = null },
        '?' => Token{ .type = .Question, .value = null },
        '|' => Token{ .type = .Or, .value = null },
        '(' => Token{ .type = .OpenParen, .value = null },
        ')' => Token{ .type = .CloseParen, .value = null },
        '[' => Token{ .type = .OpenBracket, .value = null },
        ']' => Token{ .type = .CloseBracket, .value = null },
        '^' => Token{ .type = .Caret, .value = null },
        '$' => Token{ .type = .Dollar, .value = null },
        '\\' => {
                if (i + 1 >= pattern.len) return RegexError.InvalidEscapeSequence;
                const next_character = pattern[i + 1];
                i += 1;

                switch (next_character) {
                        's' => Token{ .type = .Whitespace, .value = null },
                        'S' => Token{ .type = .NonWhitespace, .value = null },
                        'd' => Token{ .type = .Digit, .value = null },
                        'D' => Token{ .type = .NonDigit, .value = null },
                        'w' => Token{ .type = .Word, .value = null },
                        'W' => Token{ .type = .NonWord, .value = null },
                        else => Token{ .type = .EscapedCharacter, .value = next_character },
                }
        },
        else => Token{ .type = .Literal, .value = pattern[i] },
};

The nested switch statement should return whatever value it resolves to as the return value for the '\\' case. Except that if I attempt to compile this code I get this error.
src/utils/regex.zig:104:17: error: value of type 'utils.regex.Token' ignored
                switch (next_character) {
                ^~~~~~
src/utils/regex.zig:104:17: note: all non-void values must be used
src/utils/regex.zig:104:17: note: to discard the value, assign it to '_'

So it's not getting returned. Like the dumb javascript dev that I am I threw on a return statement thinking "ok, fuck it, no really return ya-silly-bitch".
        '$' => Token{ .type = .Dollar, .value = null },
        '\\' => {
                if (i + 1 >= pattern.len) return RegexError.InvalidEscapeSequence;
                const next_character = pattern[i + 1];
                i += 1;

                return switch (next_character) {
                        's' => Token{ .type = .Whitespace, .value = null },
                        'S' => Token{ .type = .NonWhitespace, .value = null },
                        'd' => Token{ .type = .Digit, .value = null },

Nope, that tries to return return from the whole function. So yeah, that doesn't work at all.
Since the documentation is inaccurate please someone who knows zig well inform me on how to return a value from a switch. Hahaha
Specs:

Mac M1
Zig version 0.13.0
Zig installed through homebrew


Can you point out where exactly in the Zig documentation it says "last line as expression ... will be returned"? Seems like you are confusing it with Rust.
And I'm confused by your question because literally the first example in your first link has the answer.

@sigod TBH I can't remember where I found it. Looking back for it I found some github conversations about removing the "feature" and some back and forth between maintainers about if it was a good idea. Source.
I too was confused because the documentation said it should work but it didn't.
I appreciate that you took the time to read my question and ask questions. Thank you.

iiuc, this is actually about blocks, so for anyone stumbling across this, here's the relevant section in the docs.

@FObersteiner Oh. Thank you! So, does this mean that my solution isn't that bad (aside from needing a more descriptive label)?

I think your solution is as intended :) Just a minor thin: I'm not sure why you would need the capture |_| in front of the label?

This is how I was able to get it to return a value.
const token = switch (c) {
        '.' => Token{ .type = .Dot, .value = null },
        '*' => Token{ .type = .Star, .value = null },
        '+' => Token{ .type = .Plus, .value = null },
        '?' => Token{ .type = .Question, .value = null },
        '|' => Token{ .type = .Or, .value = null },
        '(' => Token{ .type = .OpenParen, .value = null },
        ')' => Token{ .type = .CloseParen, .value = null },
        '[' => Token{ .type = .OpenBracket, .value = null },
        ']' => Token{ .type = .CloseBracket, .value = null },
        '^' => Token{ .type = .Caret, .value = null },
        '$' => Token{ .type = .Dollar, .value = null },
        '\\' => |_| something: {
                if (i + 1 >= pattern.len) return RegexError.InvalidEscapeSequence;
                i += 1;

                break :something switch (pattern[i]) {
                        's' => Token{ .type = .Whitespace, .value = null },
                        'S' => Token{ .type = .NonWhitespace, .value = null },
                        'd' => Token{ .type = .Digit, .value = null },
                        'D' => Token{ .type = .NonDigit, .value = null },
                        'w' => Token{ .type = .Word, .value = null },
                        'W' => Token{ .type = .NonWord, .value = null },
                        else => Token{ .type = .EscapedCharacter, .value = pattern[i] },
                };
        },
        else => Token{ .type = .Literal, .value = pattern[i] },
};


Yes, you use the switch statement as an expression.
